# Error in sorting operation on dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a file of sequences according to a certain parameter. The data looks as follows:

> ID1 ID2 32

MVKVYAPASSANMSVGFDVLGAAVTP ...

> ID1 ID2 18

MKLYNLKDHNEQVSFAQAVTQGLGKN ...

....

There are about 3000 sequences like this, i.e. the first line contains two ID field and one rank field (the sorting key) while the second one contains the sequence.  My approach is to open the file, convert the file object to a list object, separate the annotation line (ID1, ID2, rank) from the actual sequence (annotation lines always occur on even indices, while sequence lines always occur on odd indices), merge them into a dictionary and sort the dictionary using the rank field. The code reads like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("unsorted.out","rb") as f:
    f = f.readlines()

assert type(f) == list, "ERROR: file object not converted to list"

annot=[]
seq=[]

for i in range(len(f)):
    # IDs
    if i%2 == 0:
        annot.append(f[i])
    # Sequences     
    elif i%2 != 0:
        seq.append(f[i])

# Make dictionary
ids_seqs = {}         
ids_seqs = dict(zip(annot,seq))

# Solub rankings are the third field of the annot list, i.e. annot[i].split()[2]
# Use this index notation to rank sequences according to solubility measurements 

sorted_niwa = sorted(ids_seqs.items(), key = lambda val: val[0].split()[2], reverse=False)

# Save to file
with open("sorted.out","wb") as out:
    out.write("".join("%s %s" % i for i in sorted_niwa))
```

The problem I have encountered is that when I open the sorted file to inspect manually, as I scroll down I notice that some sequences have been wrongly sorted. For example, I see the rank 9 placed after rank 89. Up until a certain point the sorting is correct, but I don't understand why it hasn't worked throughout.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: you're sorting strings. "89" < "9".

Comment: @Karoly: Yes, I've just noticed as was pointed out by Kevin. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're comparing strings instead of numbers. "9" > "89" because the character '9' comes lexicographically after the character '8'. Try converting to integers in your key.

```
sorted_niwa = sorted(ids_seqs.items(), key = lambda val: int(val[0].split()[2]), reverse=False)
```

Comment: lightning quick! Thank you, I won't lie, that was a silly mistake!